# Нахождение чисел в строке

Tags: python, строки, числа

Нужно написать программу в которою юзер будет вводить символы и если там будут числа, то программа выведет их.
Я, приблизительно, в курсе что нужно создать строку А из чисел от 0 до 9. Перебирать все символы входной строки и искать их вхождение в строке А. Если есть то печатать. Но как это реализовать без понятия :((

Comment: Покажите что вы пробовали написать.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить числа как числа - кучками, а не по отдельности, то удобно использовать регулярное выражение. `re.split(r'\D+', text)` возвращает цифры сгруппироваными.

`re.split` разбивает текст (второй параметр) на подстроки/слова/токены разделённые разделителем (первый параметр). `\D` соответствует любому символу кроме цифры. `+` означает что соответствие делается по одной и больше нецифре. Префикс `r` (raw) перед строкой выключает специальную интепретацию обратных слешей в строке. Можно было без него: `r'\D+' == '\\D+'`, но с ним регулярные выражения читаются легче.

В конце и начале текста вы можете получить пустые группы. Их надо отфильтровать. `if s` проверяет строку на пустоту: `if s <=> if len(s) > 0`:

```
import re

text = 'abc123def456'

print([s for s in re.split(r'\D+', text) if s])
```

Результат:

```
['123', '456']
```

Это ещё не числа, но их уже не сложно будет пропустить через `int`.

Comment: место `if len(s) > 0` можно записать просто `if s`

Comment: Спасибо! Я знаю. `if len(s) > 0` говорит само за себя. `if s` говорит о чём? `s` это булева переменная? Объект? `None`? Нет, надо забираться в документацию и проверять. Хотя это рекомендованная практика, я ей не следую.

Comment: Уговорили. Ответ поправлен.

Answer (score 1):

Есть более лёгкий способ:

```
text = input('введите текст: ')
    
for symbol in text:
    if str(symbol).isdigit():
        print(symbol)
```

Чуть меньше кода и никаких массивов + выводит все цифры, а в коде выше, если есть 2 и более повторяющихся цифр, то выведет только одну.

Comment: `str(symbol)` писать не обязательно

Comment: @Danis, знаю, но на всякий случай предостережение, мало ли где он ещё решит это использовать А так хоть видно что это должна быть только строка)

Answer (score -1):

```py
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
text = input('введите текст: ')

for num in nums:
    if str(num) in text:
        print(num)
```

Comment: Ваш код выводит не все цифры из строки. Попробуйте ввести `111`.